# Is it safe to allocate process TLS index from kernel driver in create process notify routine

Tags: windows, multithreading, windows-kernel

Is it safe, if in `CREATE_PROCESS_NOTIFY_ROUTINE` i will allocate `TLS`(Thread local storage) index using `RtlFindClearBitsAndSet`? 
I saw, that `TlsAlloc()` routine doing that like this:

1. `RtlAcquirePebLock`
2. `RtlFindClearBitsAndSet` - `TIB->TEB->PEB->TLSBitmap`
3. `RtlReleasePebLock`

I've already tested this in user-mode, currently planning to elevate this procedure into my kernel driver ( without steps 1 and 3) for my specific operation.

So, basically, my question - is it safe?

Comment: at this point `TlsBitmap` is 0

Comment: @RbMm, thank for the answer! When `TLSBitmap` gets filled? When first thread spawns? Maybe it is better to do this in `create thread notify routine`?

Comment: i post you picture, when it filled. inside `LdrInitializeProcess`. so create thread notify routine not help here. and if say true create process notify routine called exactly when first thread created in process. so at some time as create thread notify routine. too early for your task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a process is created, the process-notify routine runs in the context of the thread that created the new process, before initial thread in new process begin executed. at this time new process `PEB` is not fully initialized. the `PEB.TlsBitmap` member from `PEB` is 0 at this point. *ntdll.dll* in new process later asign it to not exported global variable - `ntdll.TlsBitmap`. so question event not safe/unsafe. simply impossible
[image]

Comment: @Kracken - not, not better. `CreateThreadNotify` called  before thread begin executed in user mode